# Twitter Oauth Statuses/show in codeigniter returns error

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, oauth

I am using [this](https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth) library for implementing twitter Oauth in my project,
and codeigniter if that is relevant in this case.

I am trying to get a tweet based on the tweet id, but it's returning an error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
public function gettweetbyid() {
    $this->config->load('twitter');
    $consumer = $this->config->item('twitter_consumer_token');
    $consumer_secret = $this->config->item('twitter_consumer_secret');
    $access_token = $this->config->item('twitter_access_token');
    $access_token_secret = $this->config->item('twitter_access_secret');
    $connection = $this->twitteroauth->create($consumer, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->get('id')
    );
    $tweets = $this->twitteroauth->get('statuses/show', $data);

    echo json_encode($tweets);
}
```

I know everything is right because I am using the plugin as well to get tweets based on a hashtag, and this is no problem at all.

The URl I am getting looks very similar to their docs url:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=408541017676460000&....
```

I'm looking at this for a whole day now and my time is running out...

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Also, is there any way on twitter I can check if the ID actually exists? Altho I don't think that is the problem, I'd like to know for future reference

Comment: I see this when the user, twitter etc twitter object is deleted/removed and does actually not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those people stumbling on this:

I get the id from a previous request to twitter, and I found out you have to use the `id_str` from the json data twitter returns, and not the normal `id`. the string id and normal id are different. God may know why, but I'm just glad this got solved!

Comment: Are you sure? I've always found the id and id_str for users, tweets etc. resources to be the same, one is the just the stringified version of the long value.

Comment: I am 99,9% sure. When I try to get the data from twitter after pulling a tweet id from my database, it gives me the error above. I tried saving the `id_str` in my database and getting a tweet with this, and it works perfect. I read somewhere that you have to give it like `'id' => '123456'` instead of `'id' => 123456`. Even tho PHP gives back the `id` as string, and not as an integer. The docs also say that they are indeed the same, like you said. Still find it weird it didn't work with the `id`. If anyone can give an explanation, that'd be nice!

Comment: You have to send it as string in request and not number/int/long